# C# - Wait for a WebBrowser to completely finish navigating and loading a website/webpage

Tags: c#, browser-automation

I'm trying to do web automation by creating a Windows Form application in C# using WebBrowser. I currently have the code below that navigates to Youtube and inputs a string in Youtube's search bar.

```
website.Navigate("www.youtube.com");

website.Document.GetElementById("search").InnerText = "Cavaliers vs Boston highlights";
```

However, I get a NullReferenceException in the line

> website.Document.GetElementById("search").InnerText = "Cavaliers vs Boston highlights";

I tried searching in different websites on how a WebBrowser is able to determine if it has completely finished loading the website you have specified in the Navigate method but so far I haven't found any.

What I have found online are methods that checks a WebBrowser's ready state but upon trying it, it doesn't even load the Form I created, yet still proceeds to the GetElementById method.

Hoping someone can help me with this, been trying to find a solution since morning.

Comment: notice you can use Youtube's query string to go straight to the search results if that's what you're after. `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Cavaliers+vs+Boston+highlights`

Comment: This is actually very helpful, I'll keep this in mind. However, I need to be able to do something after I have loaded Youtube (like click a video, etc) that's why I need to know how a WebBrowser is able to determine if it has finished loading something.

Comment: to manipulate the DOM you need to wait for the DOM to finish loading first. to do that use the `DocumentCompleted` event of the browser control. as suggested by Quirzo below. the webbrowser control (ieframe) has poor performance, and is way to old to be used elegantly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an event listener to WebBrowser. The WebBrowser has a [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event that occurs when the web page has been fully loaded.

Something like

```
public frmMain()
{
    website.DocumentCompleted += website_DocumentCompleted;
}


public void website_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    website.Document.GetElementById("search").InnerText = "Cavaliers vs Boston highlights"
}
```

where frmMain is your form. It could be of course added in somewhere else too.

Comment: May I ask what parameters I need to pass to this method? It mentions 2 parameters of type object and WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs but I currently don't have that in my code. Is this something new that I must create?

Comment: website.Navigate("www.youtube.com");

website_DocumentCompleted();

public void website_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            website.Document.GetElementById("search").InnerText = "Cavaliers vs Boston highlights";
        }

Comment: I tried doing this, but I still get NullReferenceException.

Comment: You can add the method automatically by double clicking DocumentCompleted method in Forms designer properties. So right click the web browser in designer, select events and double click the DocumentCompleted. Other way is to add in manually for example at form constructor: `website.DocumentCompleted += website_DocumentCompleted;` EDIT: Updated answer.

Comment: I tried doing as you said but it still gives me a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Perhaps you shoud try your code first by adding a button and click it when the page is loaded to see if it works in a first place.

Comment: It seems the issue is actually with Youtube. I tried replacing the website with Facebook and it worked. I don't know why but GetElementById("search") does not work in Youtube.

Comment: Well thats good news, I hope you will get it done. Perhaps there just is no id="search" element in the YouTube page? Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks Quirzo, you too. When I inspect element Youtube, that's the id it has so I'm not sure why I am not able to get it. I don't think it's possible that an element ID has a duplicate in the same webpage, right?

Comment: The standard says that id should be always unique I think, but it's still of course possible to add multiple of same ids just by doing so.